# web3.js: function web3.eth.Contract(abi, address) failed to initiate a contract instance

Tags: node.js, smartcontracts, web3js

I am trying to interact with a smart contract deployed on a local Ethereum node under the help of web3.js library. Unfortunately, `web3.eth.Contract(abi, address)` seems to fail in initiating a contract instance.

---

【Snippits】The entire `app.js` file shows as below:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

const abi = [{"anonymous": false,"inputs": [{"indexed": false,"name": "add","type": "int256"},{"indexed": false,"name": "name","type": "string"},{"indexed": true,"name": "id","type": "uint256"},{"indexed": true,"name": "checked","type": "bool"}],"name": "globalValueChanged","type": "event"},{"constant": false,"inputs": [{"name": "add","type": "int256"},{"name": "name","type": "string"},{"name": "id","type": "uint256"},{"name": "checked","type": "bool"}],"name": "modifyGlobalValue","outputs": [{"name": "","type": "int256"}],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "nonpayable","type": "function"},{"inputs": [],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "nonpayable","type": "constructor"},{"constant": true,"inputs": [],"name": "getGlobalValue","outputs": [{"name": "","type": "int256"}],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "view","type": "function"},{"constant": true,"inputs": [{"name": "times","type": "int256"}],"name": "testGlobalValue","outputs": [{"name": "","type": "int256"}],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "view","type": "function"}]
const address = '0x9f6c4e63cbca51dea852a579c907317a0eac138c';
const contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);

// to test if initialized web3 works fine
web3.eth.getAccounts().then((results) => {
    console.log("***web3.eth.getAccounts()***:")
    console.log(results)
})

// to test if web3.eth.Contract works
console.log("***contractInstance.abi***:")
console.log(contractInstance.abi)
```

---

【Outputs】Outputs of running `node app.js`.

```
**contractInstance.abi***:
undefined
***web3.eth.getAccounts()***:
[ '0x135B02baD443C1073C14F8a7f13cEc8661d3eC3d',
  '0x69890d19B6eb060cA47e1ca41d93256E46bb7195' ]
```

The `web3.eth.getAccounts()` returns correct values, while `web3.eth.Contract(abi, address)` seems to fail to initiate a contract instance.

---

【Addtional Information】

1. `npm list web` outputs `web3@1.0.0-beta.52`.
2. Other web3 functions like web3.eth.getAccounts() works fine.
3. In geth console, with the same value of `abi` and `address`, `eth.contract(abi).at(address)` works fine.

Comment: try with await const contractInstance = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);

Comment: It got an error `await is only valid in async function
    at new Script 
`

Comment: The code works fine with `web3@1.0.0-beta.37`

Comment: const async contractInstance = new await web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);

Comment: Not working, though. :-(
`/usr/zouhuan/Ethereum/Event/Demo/app.js:9
const async contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
      ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration`

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is caused by latest release `web3@1.0.0-beta.52`? I got expected outputs when working with `web3@1.0.0-beta.37`.